# Cannot find polygons within polygons using spatial LINQ queries

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, postgis, nettopologysuite

I loaded [this](https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/canada/quebec.html) (Quebec) OSM PBF file in my PostgreSQL database and from a .NET Core Web Api, I'm trying to do basic queries, like finding polygons within a specified area, but getting no results.

I have scaffolded a `DbContext` using this command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=52.0.0.0;Database=my-db;Username=postgres;Password=password" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -OutputDir Models
```

I got this error though:

> Could not find type mapping for column 'public.planet_osm_polygon.way'
>   with data type 'geometry(Geometry,3857)'. Skipping column. Unable to
>   scaffold the index 'planet_osm_polygon_way_idx'. The following columns
>   could not be scaffolded: way.

So I manually added this property to the `PlanetOsmPolygon.cs` that was produced by the command

```
public Geometry Way { get; set; }
```

Weird thing is I do have `Geometry` available as I can declare a variable of that type and compile properly....

I think I have properly set up the context for PostgreSQL and PostGIS

```
services.AddDbContext<OSMContext>(x =>
{   
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SQL:Prod");
        x.UseNpgsql(connectionString, o =>
        {
            o.CommandTimeout(240);
            o.UseNetTopologySuite();

        });

}, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Here's the API method code

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();

//values are from query string
//north=45.5154045103725&south=45.4901382447544&west=-73.5854034422038&east=-73.5493545534017

Polygon space = geometryFactory.CreatePolygon(new Coordinate[] {
            new Coordinate(west, south),
            new Coordinate(east, south),
            new Coordinate(east, north),
            new Coordinate(west, north),
            new Coordinate(west, south) });

//var polygons = OSMContext.PlanetOsmPolygon.Where(x => x.Way.Covers(space)).ToList();
//var polygons = OSMContext.PlanetOsmPolygon.Where(x => x.Way.CoveredBy(space)).ToList();
//var polygons = OSMContext.PlanetOsmPolygon.Where(x => space.Covers(x.Way)).ToList();
//var polygons = OSMContext.PlanetOsmPolygon.Where(x => x.Way.Covers(space)).ToList();
var polygons = OSMContext.PlanetOsmPolygon.Where(x => x.Way.Within(space)).ToList();
```

As you can see, I've tried a few way around this, with no results ever. `space` is valid (`IsValid` returns true).

Is it the values that I'm using for `space` that may be a problem ? Or that scaffold issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The OSM data is saved using CRS 3857.

The bounding box is created using WGS 84 (4326), but you haven't specified the CRS.

To fix it, you can specify the bounding box coordinates in 3857, or you can project the current 4326 box to 3857.